# show No-Overlay (transparent background) when using backdrop:"static" in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable closing of bootstrap modal when clicking outside of modal, this I can achieve through applying `backdrop:"static"` but the problem is it adds the dark-overlay to the background of modal.
How can I prevent it?
I can override the CSS property but it'll get applied for each modal (which I don't want)

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use more specific CSS rule for modal you want to exclude overlay, e.g: `#myModal1.in ~.modal-backdrop {
    opacity: 0;  
}`   http://jsfiddle.net/tjyazbzL/

Comment: @A.Wolff but clicking outside is closing the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are showing modal through `js` then after `js` e.g. (`$(modalid).modal('show')`) code for which `modal` is shown, then add `$(".modal-backdrop.in").css("opacity","0");`

Comment: No, I'm making a ajax call to get modal. then setting it as  $("#LeadTagControl").modal({
                                    backdrop: "static",
                                    keyboard: false
                                });

Comment: after `$("#LeadTagControl").modal({ backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });` line add `$(".modal-backdrop.in").css("opacity","0");`